# de-duplicate rows and align columns in R

Tags: r, duplicates, metadata, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe where there are duplicate samples but the reason for this is that only variable appears per row:

| Sample | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | NA |
| B | NA | 1 |
| A | NA | 3 |
| C | NA | 2 |
| C | 5 | NA |
| B | 4 | NA |

I would like to end up with the row names de-duplicated and corresponding column values side-by-side:

| Sample | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 |
| B | 4 | 1 |
| C | 5 | 2 |

I've tried the group_by() function and that failed miserably!

I would very much appreciate any assistance and happy to clarify anything further if required!

Answer (score 3):

We could use `group_by` and `summarise` for this task. Getting the `max()` will give us the desired output:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Sample) %>% 
  summarise(across(, ~max(., na.rm=TRUE)))
```

```
  Sample  Var1  Var2
  <chr>  <int> <int>
1 A          1     3
2 B          4     1
3 C          5     2
```

Comment: What if all values are `NA` in some group? E.g. `df$Var1[1] <- NA` and your code will get `-Inf`.

Comment: Thank you @DarrenTsai. I think we then need to further tweak the data. But I tried and it gives a warning no error. Do you have any idea.  For example adding this line `  mutate(across(, ~ifelse(. == -Inf, NA, .)))` will remove the -Inf and add NA but the Warning message will remain.

Comment: Your workaround is great! I may use `across(, ~ ifelse(all(is.na(.x)), NA, max(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)

DT <- fread("Sample     Var1    Var2
A   1   NA
B   NA  1
A   NA  3
C   NA  2
C   5   NA
B   4   NA")

# or setDT(DT) if DT is not a data.table format
# melt to long format, and remove NA's
DT.melt <- melt(DT, id.vars = "Sample", na.rm = TRUE)
# cast to wide again
dcast(DT.melt, Sample ~ variable, fill = NA)
#    Sample Var1 Var2
# 1:      A    1    3
# 2:      B    4    1
# 3:      C    5    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
fmax(df1[-1], g = df1$Sample)
  Var1 Var2
A    1    3
B    4    1
C    5    2
```

---

Or in `dplyr` 1.1.0, we can also use `.by` in `reframe`

```
df1 %>%
   reframe(across(where(is.numeric), ~ max(.x,  na.rm = TRUE)), .by = 'Sample')
  Sample Var1 Var2
1      A    1    3
2      B    4    1
3      C    5    2
```